# Databinding to array adapter only works with model in root folder

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm trying to bind objects to my arrayadapter.  However, the generated binding doesn't work when I have my model outside of my root folder.

So this works:

```
app
- Class
```

And this doesn't:

```
app
- Models
   - Class
```

I've been fixing an issue with my databinding for a while now and this was the fix. The generator kept including generating "Models.Class" as the targeted binding model.

Any idea why this happens? Having the model class in my root folder isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently folder names are case sensitive, changing to "model" correctly generates binding.